# Using JSON schema to restrict values by existing keys in .json file

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema

I am currently trying write a JSON Schema to validate a catalogue in .json file format.

It contains information about some of the possible components of an assembly and then several entries for actual assemblies, which consists of strings referencing those components (via the key in the .json) file.

The .json file looks something like this:

```
{
    "sensors" : {
            "sensor_type_temperature_1" : { ... info about first temperature sensor ... },
            "sensor_type_tempearature_2" : { ... info about second temperature sensor ... },
            "sensor_type_humidity_1" : { ... info about first humidity sensor ... }, ...
        }, ...
    "masts" : {
            "mast_type_1" : { ... info about first mast type ... },
            "mast_type_2" : { ... info about second mast type ... }, ...
        }, ...
    "observation_stations" : {
            "first_station" : {
                    "sensors" : ["sensor_id_tempearature_2", "sensor_id_humidity_1"],
                    "mast" : "mast_type_2",
                    "location" : { ... location ...}, ...
            "second_station" : {
                    "sensors" : ["sensor_id_tempearature_1"],
                    "mast" : "mast_type_1",
                    "location" : { ... location ...}, ...
                }
        }
}
```

What I want to do now is to use a JSON Schema to validate my file. I am fine for the data formats and I am familiar with using enums for restricting the actual content of e.g. contents of the "mast" or "sensors".

How can I use the scheme to verify that all entries in of "sensors" and "mast" in an observation station are also keys in the "sensors" and "masts" section of the same .json file?

Comment: There is no way to validate that with json schema. You will have to perform this validation programmatically, on your own.

Comment: Thank you. It seemed like a standard problem to me, so I expected it to be supported. Do you want to make your comment an answer?

Comment: No, it is fine, thanks :)